# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. For Loop

Tags: vb.net

```
Function FindUserByCriteria(ByVal _state As String, ByVal _county As String, ByVal _status As String, ByVal _client As String, ByVal _department As String, ByVal _ordernumber As String) As DataTable
    'Code to load user criteria from database
    Dim ordertype As String
    If _status = "Online" Then
        ordertype = "Online"
    ElseIf _status = "Tax Cert Call" Then
        ordertype = "Call"
    End If



    Dim TaxConnStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Database")
    Dim dbConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(TaxConnStr)
    Try

        Dim queryString As String

        queryString = "Select Username, Amount, Rank FROM UserCriteria "
        queryString += "WHERE UserCriteria.State = '" & _state & "' AND UserCriteria.County = '" & _county & "' AND UserCriteria.Status = '" & _status & "' AND UserCriteria.Client = '" & _client & "' AND UserCriteria.Department = '" & _department & "' AND UserCriteria.OrderNumber = '" & _ordernumber & "';"


        Dim dbCommand As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand
        dbCommand.CommandText = queryString
        dbCommand.Connection = dbConnection
        Dim dataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = dbCommand
        Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)


        If dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count >= 1 Then
            FindUserByCriteria = dataSet.Tables(0)
        End If


        Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf)
        For i = 0 To FindUserByCriteria.Rows.Count - 1
            If Not IsUserOnline(FindUserByCriteria.Rows(i).Item("UserName")) Then
                FindUserByCriteria.Rows(i).Delete()
            End If
        Next
        FindUserByCriteria.AcceptChanges()


    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        myLogger.Log(ex.Message)
        SendMail(ex.Message)
    Finally
        dbConnection.Close()
    End Try

End Function
```

So, i get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error at the

```
For i = 0 To FindUserByCriteria.Rows.Count - 1
```

line. I swear this was working for me not just 3 days ago...not sure what has changed in my code recently to make this error pop up. Any help would be nice.

Comment: What happens when `dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count = 0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to reverse the for loop for

```
 For i = FindUserByCriteria.Rows.Count - 1 to 0 step -1
```

you need to delete backward otherwise you will reach an index already deleted

or you simply need to put the use of any FindUserByCriteria inside the if where it get set

```
    If dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count >= 1 Then
        FindUserByCriteria = dataSet.Tables(0)


        Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf)
        For i = 0 To FindUserByCriteria.Rows.Count - 1
            If Not IsUserOnline(FindUserByCriteria.Rows(i).Item("UserName")) Then
                FindUserByCriteria.Rows(i).Delete()
            End If
        Next
        FindUserByCriteria.AcceptChanges()
    End If
```